# Opendaylight Sodium-SR2 problem with installation

Tags: opendaylight

Sorry, this is quite low level. I'm having issues with installing ODL Sodium on Ubuntu stretch i386.
The install works well, Karaf is available, I can install features and port 8181 is coming up. The issue is when I use a browser to access the GUI interface I get a 401 (Unauthorised) instead of a login.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885859/13200212

Answer (score 0):

what features are you installing? The GUI (DLUX) has not been available for several releases of ODL now, so maybe it's just not there.

Comment: I'm basically looking for a gui/presentation layer. ODL seems to be heading down the headless path